# Email doesn't show more than 9 images

Tags: python, html, email

I wanna send an email automatically using python, and the code is as follows:

The content of the email looks like this:

```
    <table border="2">
    <tr><th>Mx</th>
    <th coslanb="5"> < img src="cid:image1" alt="image1" width="600" height="300" />< img src="cid:image2" alt="image2" width="500" height="300" /></th></tr>              
    <tr><th>Tger</th>
    <th coslanb="5"> < img src="cid:image3" alt="image3" width="600" height="300" />< img src="cid:image4" alt="image4" width="500" height="300" /></th></tr>  
    <tr><th>1912</th>
     <th coslanb="5"> < img src="cid:image5" alt="image5" width="600" height="300" />< img src="cid:image6" alt="image6" width="500" height="300" /></th></tr>          
     <tr><th>Gold</th>
     <th coslanb="5"> < img src="cid:image7" alt="image7" width="600" height="300" />< img src="cid:image8" alt="image8" width="500" height="300" /></th></tr>             
     <tr><th>Abnormal</th>
     <th coslanb="5">< img src="cid:image9" alt="image9" width="300" height="400" /> < img src="cid:image10" alt="image10" width="800" height="400" /></th></tr>
```

then I code this to add image into my email.

```
Files = [path1,...,path10]
i = 1
for filepath in Files:
        f = open(filepath,'rb')
        msgImage = MIMEImage(f.read())
        f.close()
        msgImage.add_header('Content-ID','image%s'%i)
        msg.attach(msgImage)
        i = i +1
```

Finally, I find the 10th image isn't displayed. I've tried to change the sort of image but it doesn't work. I wanna figure the problem and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I 've solved this problem by changing the code msgImage.add_header('Content-ID','image%s'%i) to ''%i
I think the problem is the header of the image added.